# Last for loop problem for roman to numeral

Tags: c++

Can someone help me find whats the problem with my code?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream roman("C:/OT2015/Rimski.txt");
    ofstream arabic("C:/OT2015/Arapski.txt");
    string line;

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    getline( roman,line);
    int numbers[line.length()] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        if(line[i] == 'I'){
            numbers[i] = 1;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'V'){
            numbers[i] = 5;
        }        
        if(line[i] == 'X'){
            numbers[i] = 10;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'L'){
            numbers[i] = 50;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'C'){
            numbers[i] = 100;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'D'){
            numbers[i] = 500;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'M'){
            numbers[i] = 1000;
        }
        count++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1]){
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }
        else{
            sum = sum - numbers[i];
        }
    }

    cout << sum;
    arabic << sum;
}
```

The problem is with the last for loop, which adds up the numbers incorrectly.
When i use the debugger, it goes haywire and misplace my breakpoint to somewhere else. It would also skip the first conditional if and jump straight to the else and would add up to -10.I fixed it but it still outputs the number -10.

Roman numeral that i tested: LXXIV
The correct output: 74
My output(incorrect): -10

please help

Comment: What will `numbers[i+1]` contain where `i` = `count -1` (on the last iteration of your loop).

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I added another if loop where i != count - 1 and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i added another if loop when i added george's comment and it worked

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream  roman("C:/OT2015/Rimski.txt");
    ofstream arabic("C:/OT2015/Arapski.txt");
    string line;

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    getline( roman,line);
    int numbers[line.length()] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        if(line[i] == 'I'){
            numbers[i] = 1;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'V'){
            numbers[i] = 5;
        }        
        if(line[i] == 'X'){
            numbers[i] = 10;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'L'){
            numbers[i] = 50;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'C'){
            numbers[i] = 100;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'D'){
            numbers[i] = 500;
        }
        if(line[i] == 'M'){
            numbers[i] = 1000;
        }
        count++;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
       if(i != count - 1){ 
        if(numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1]){
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }
        else{
            sum = sum - numbers[i];
        }
       }
       else{
           sum = sum + numbers[i];
       }


    }

    cout << sum;
    arabic << sum;
```

just gotta wait 2 days to mark as answer